# For fixed $t$ with $0 \le t < 1$, prove that $x \mapsto [x, t]$ defines a homeomorphism from a space $X$ to a subspace of the cone $CX$.

Tags: general-topology

> For fixed $t$ with $0  \le t < 1$, prove that $x \mapsto [x, t]$ defines a homeomorphism from a space $X$ to a subspace of the cone $CX$.

Let $\varphi : X \to \varphi(X)$ be the map defined by $x \mapsto [x,t]$. Then $\varphi$ is clearly surjective as the codomain is defined to be the image of it. To prove that $\varphi$ is injective I considered the standard approach to assume that $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y) \implies [x,t]=[y,t]$, but I don't think I can conclude from here that $x=y$? I am also wondering what is the idea with $t <1$ being a strict inequality? Are we excluding the vertex of the cone here, if so why?

Comment: (1) Remember that you need more than injectivity + surjectivity, you also need continuity of the map and its inverse. (2) Remember also that $CX$ is a quotient of $X \times [0,1]$, so that $[x,t]$ represents a single ordered pair $(x,t)$ when $t<1$. Can you then show that $[x,t]=[y,t]$ implies $x=y$? (3) If $X$ has more than one point, is it going to be homeomorphic to the vertex of the cone? That's why $t=1$ is excluded.

Comment: Oh I misread you comment. Why would $[x,t]=[y,t]$ imply that $x=y$ even if $[x,t]$ represents the equivalence class of $(x,t)$? Couldn't there be two distinct points $x,y$ that give the same equivalence class?

Comment: The equivalence relation on $X \times [0,1]$ that we are considering is the one that "collapses" the top of the cylinder over $X$ into a single point (i.e. $(x,1) \sim (y,1)$ for every $x,y \in X$). The remaining part of the cylinder ($X \times [0,1)$) is unaffected. Can you identify the equivalence classes of this relation? (hint: there are two cases to consider: $t = 1$ and $t \neq 1$)

Comment: The equivalence classes of the cone are just the singletons $\{(x,t)\}$ if $t \ne 1$ right? They aren't affected by the imposed equivalence relation.

Comment: Exactly. Basically, the subset of the cone which does not include the vertex is just the same thing as the cylinder without the top face (that is $X \times [0,1)$)

Comment: I've tried to explain this in my answer, let me know if you need further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the fact that $\varphi : X \to \varphi(X)$ is injective follows from the definition of the equivalence relation on the cone, since for $t < 1$ the equivalence classes are singletons, that is $[x,t] = \{(x,t)\}$ for every $t \in [0,1)$ and $x \in X$.

Now, for the continuity we need to look at open sets in $\varphi(X)$ and check that their preimages are open in $X$. By the definition of the quotient topology induced by an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a space $W$, a set $U \subset W/\sim$ is open if and only if the set $\{w \in W \; | \; [w] \in U\}$ is open in $W$.

In our case $W = X \times [0,1]$ and $\sim$ is the relation on $X \times [0,1]$ defined by $(x,1) \sim (y,1)$ for every $x, y \in X$ (hence $W/\sim = CX$). Thus, a set $U \subset CX$ is open if and only $\{(x,t) \in X \times [0,1] \; | \; [x,t] \in U\}$ is open in $X \times I$.

Since we are only interested in subsets of $CX$ which do not contain the vertex, we know that $[x,t] = \{(x,t)\}$ for every equivalence class $[x,t]$ in our subset. This implies that a subset $U$ (of the cone without the vertex) is open if and only if $\{(x,t) \in X \times [0,1) \; | \; \{(x,t)\} \in U\}$ is open in $X \times [0,1)$, that is if $U$, seen as a subspace of $X \times [0,1)$ is open in $X \times [0,1)$ (since the subset of the cone without the vertex is "the same" (up to renaming $[x,t]$ to $(x,t)$) as the subset of the cylinder without its upper base).
Fixing $t = t_0$ and using the definition of open sets of the subspace topology, we see that a subset $U$ of $\varphi(X)$ is open if and only if $\{(x,t_0) \in X \times \{t_0\} \; | \; [x,t_0] \in U\}$ is open in $X \times \{t_0\}$.

Now you can conclude with the definition of the open sets in the product topology $X \times \{t_0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still not sure why is $\{(x,t_0) \in X \times \{t_0\} \; | \; [x,t_0] \in U\}$ open in $X \times \{t_0\}$?

Comment: The space we are considering, $\varphi(X)$ is a subset of the cone for a fixed $t = t_0$, so it is of the form $(X \times \{t_0\})/\sim$, where the equivalence relation does not affect our space since it only associates points when $t= 1$. This implies that being open in $\varphi(X) = (X \times \{t_0\})/ \sim$ is equivalent to being open in $X \times \{t_0\}$. More precisely, the two spaces are homeomorphic and the homeomorphism is given by the simple bijection $[x,t] \mapsto (x,t)$

Comment: I understood this from you answer, but in order to conclude continuity I need $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ to be open for any $U$ open in $\varphi(X)$. Even if $U$ being open in $\varphi(X)$ is equivalent to $U$ being open in $X \times \{t_0\}$ it's still not giving information about the preimage of $U$ under $\varphi$. What I have is that $U$ open in $\varphi(X)$ implies that $U = V \cap \varphi(X)$ for $V$ open in $CX$ so $$\varphi^{-1}(U)=\varphi^{-1}(V \cap \varphi(X)) = \varphi^{-1}(V) \cap X = \varphi^{-1}(V).$$

Comment: Now because $V$ is open in $CX$ if and only if $\varphi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ we can conclude that $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Yes, you found a much nicer way to conclude. What I was trying to say with my last statement is that knowing that the sets $\mathcal{U} \times \{t_0\}$ with $\mathcal{U}$ open in $X$ (and $\emptyset$) form a basis for the product topology on $X \times \{t_0\}$, then you know that the preimage of $U$ under $\varphi$, which is the first component of the product, is open in $X$ (being a union of open sets). But your strategy is definitively more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a picture helps. Basically you're just trying to show that slices of the cylinder embed into the cone as long as $t\neq 1.$

Fix $0\le t<1.$ Then, $[x,t]\sim [y,t]\Leftrightarrow  x=y$ because by definition of $\sim$, the equivalence classes are singletons when $0\le t<1.$ You have shown that $\varphi $ is continuous. So all you need to show is that it is an open map $\textit{onto}$ its image, $\varphi(X)$ with the $\textit{subspace}$ topology of the quotient topology on $C(X).$

Therefore, let $U\subseteq X$ be open. We want to show that $\varphi (U)$is open in $\varphi (X).$ This means we should find an open set $V$ in $C(X)$ such that $V\cap \varphi(X)=\varphi(U).$

But this is easy. Note that $V=U\times [0,1)$ is an open set in $C(X).$ And $V\cap \varphi(X)=U\times \{t\}=\varphi(U).$

Comment: I don't think I've showed that $\varphi$ is continuous here?

Comment: You just need to take an open set $V$ in $\varphi(X)$ in the subspace topology and show that $\varphi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. It's almost a verbatim copy of my answer.

Comment: The openness of the set $\varphi^{-1}(V) = \{x \in X \mid [x,t] \in V\}$ is not clear to me. Is the correct interpretation that this is the preimage of a "slice" of the cone?

Comment: An open set $V$ in $\varphi(X)$ is $V=V'\cap \varphi(X)$ for some open set $V'$ in $C(X)$. So, you need to  know what the open sets are in $C(X).$ This seems to be your problem!

Comment: But $C(X)$ has the quotient topology. The open sets are the subsets $U \subset C(X)$ for which $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open. But I don't think it tells me anything about the intersection $V' \cap \varphi(X)$?

Comment: Hint: take an $[x,t]\in C(X).$ Either $t=1$ or it isn't. Conisder each case separately, and use the definition of the quotient topology to see what an open set $V'$ about $[x,t]$ looks like.

Comment: If $t \ne 1$ is the open set containing $[x,t]$ just the product $U \times \{t\}$ for $U$ open in $X$ containing $x$?